# WhiteSpace programming language multipliction two numbers

Tags: whitespace-language

how can I multipiction two numbers in WhiteSpace?

for example

input:

32 3

output:

96

I searched tutorial for this, but i don't found this

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication operation is `[space][LF]`.